# how to make a highscore function in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm having trouble creating a score function in pygame here is what I have come up with but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
    def highest_things_dodged(ns, hs):
       font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 25)
       score = font.render("Highscore: "+str(hs), True, black)
       while True:
         if ns > hs:
          hs+ns
          gameDisplay.blit(scr,(50,0))
```

If anyone knows how to solve the problem please comment
Thanks

Comment: hs+ns does nothing useful.

Comment: Details please. What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean - other than the obvious.

Comment: don't use `while True` except for main loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do but here is a simple example:

```
if score > highscore:
    highscore = score
```